# ?z waiting to receive.**B0100000023be50 when I use rz to upload file

Tags: networking, modem

I'm connected from my Mac to a remote Linux machine. I'm following the steps of a tutorial, and after installing the `lrzsz` package it told me to run the `rz` command. In the tutorial it opened a window to pick the files, but in my case I get stuck here:

```
[root@localhost /]# rz
?**B0100000023be50ive.**B0100000023be50
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you reading a _really old_ book?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are seeing is the request (from `rz`) to its remote side (yours) to initiate a [ZMODEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZMODEM) upload.

The obvious questions here would be: Are you using a ZMODEM-capable terminal? Are you starting a ZMODEM upload after starting `rz` on the remote end?

`rz` comes with a companion program `sz` (the names most likely originated as shorthands for "receive ZMODEM" and "send ZMODEM", respectively). After starting `rz` on the remote system (or otherwise triggering the remote system to expect a ZMODEM upload), you have to start the actual upload on your system; on a *nix system, that would commonly be done by starting `sz` with appropriate parameters, and tying the two together somehow. The two utilities will then communicate back and forth with each other to transfer the file and ensure that it is transferred without errors. (Remember that ZMODEM originated at a time when error correction was a luxury and automated retransmission was the exception rather than the norm.)

Terminal programs at the time differed in how they handled ZMODEM requests; some would automatically start the upload or download process when seeing the trigger packet, whereas others required manual action to do so. I remember how amazed I was when using [Terminate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminate_(software)) back in the day that it would start the upload or download automatically instead of requiring me to go through extra steps to start the file transfer locally.

Unless you have a specific reason to use ZMODEM for file transfer, it's probably easier to use something like sftp/scp, the infrastructure for which (ssh) you should have set up anyway for the terminal connection if it's a remote system.